# Getting Member Data From WhishList Member on Register

Tags: php, plugin-development

I contacted WLM tech support and asked:

> "I'm using the WishList Member API is there a way I could figure out if a new member has been added to Wishlist? I'd like to capture the newest member's name and email address and then use that it in my plugin."

They responded with:

> "You can use wishlistmember_shoppingcart_register (action).
>
> Called when a new member is signed-up via one of the shopping cart integrations. Information about the registration can be found in the $_POST variable."

I'm wondering how to do this... should I use an action?

```
add_action('wishlistmember_shoppingcart_register', 'get_member_info'));

function get_member_info(){
    //get $_POST
   // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Also, should I use this code in my plugin and add the shortcode to the Wordpress page with the form on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the link below and read on how to use add_action correctly.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

```
add_action('wishlistmember_shoppingcart_register', 'get_member_info'));

function get_member_info() {
    // Debug $_POST.
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_POST);
    exit;
}
```